# std::sort for sorting a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, vector

```
void BloodDonationPoint::sortBlood()
{
   std::sort(bloodBank.begin(), bloodBank.end(), isOlder);
}

bool BloodDonationPoint::isOlder(BloodUnit* a, BloodUnit* b)
{
    return a->getTimeToGoingBad()<b->getTimeToGoingBad();
}

error C3867: 'BloodDonationPoint::isOlder': non-standard syntax; use '&' to 
create a pointer to member
error C2672: 'sort': no matching overloaded function found
error C2780: 'void std::sort(const _RanIt,const _RanIt)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
```

Why doesen't it work? Bloodbank is just a vector of pointers to BloodUnits.

Comment: `BloodDonationPoint::isOlder` needs to be static.

Comment: Start my resolving the warning. (Hint: `isOlder` has no reason to be a member of  BloodDonationPoint, or anything.)